# postgres vacuum_freeze_min_age vs autovacuum_freeze_min_age

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I fail to understand why `pg_settings` parameter `vacuum_freeze_min_age` is named differently than the table parameter `autovacuum_freeze_min_age`. Isn't the purpose of this setting on table level to overwrite the general setting? Shouldn't they share the same name then, as it is true for `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` for example? What knowledge am I missing to make sense of this? TY

Please see below:

```
select version();
-- PostgreSQL 14.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit
select name from pg_settings where name like '%vacuum_freeze_min_age'; 
-- vacuum_freeze_min_age
create table t (c int);
alter table t set (vacuum_freeze_min_age = '1');
-- SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: unrecognized parameter "vacuum_freeze_min_age"
alter table t set (autovacuum_freeze_min_age = '1');
select reloptions from pg_class where relname = 't';
-- {autovacuum_freeze_min_age=1}
```

Comment: There is no `autovacuum_freeze_min_age`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe not on pg_settings level, but on table level, please see the code that I added to the question.

Comment: Ah, you are speaking about the storage parameter. I don't know why the name is different; perhaps to show that it is only used for autovacuum.